# I'm getting an warning in the JasperReports how to resolve it?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new to *JasperReports*, i have added the plugin to my netbeans IDE, am trying to create an report using table, i have also designed an table in the *iReport* designer and i have connected it to the sql database, when i click the preview button am getting the following warning

> Blockquote net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :       1. Warning : Element bottom reaches outside band area : y=0 height=140 band-height=61     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:271)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:354)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:270)     at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(JasperCompileManager.java:563)     at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:528)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)     at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)

Kindly help me to resolve this warning friends thanks in advance

Comment: Your report's design is invalid

Comment: Some times WE don't know anything in something that's why I give you my point. Regards,

Answer (score 11):

It clearly says `"Element bottom reaches outside band area : y=0 height=140 band-height=61"` which means  you have an element with coordinate y=0 and height=140. So your band height must be greater than 0+140 = 140. But currently it is 61 as stated in error message.

Comment: is it possible to let the height be 140 and the band height be less than that? I ask as I want a line that spans the entire page from top to bottom..